# Como poner un Boton footer de un cuadro HTML CSS

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy recien entrado en el mundo de html y css, casi 2 semanas estoy haciendo estos cuadros,pero quisiera que la parte de rojito que es un boton,que le quite sus propiedades (wight,line height,etc) por eso se ve asi,quisiera que siempre permanezca abajo del cuadrado,solo esta abajo cuando el texto es abundante.
Probe con bottom 0,pero me sale mal,no pongo el css ya que supongo que esta mal.,pero pongo el html.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="hospital">
<div class="hospital-img">
  <img src="img/huesitos.png">
</div>
<div class="hospital-description">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Traumatologia</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nos encargamos  de las lesiones traumáticas de columna y extremidades que afectan a: Huesos: fracturas (fractura de femur, fractura de húmero, fractura de Colles), epifisiólisis, etc.                         </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div class="book">
  <a href="#">Más Informacion</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hotel {
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  width:25%;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.hotel li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.hotel-img {

  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hotel-description {
 text-align: justify;
  width: 90%;
}

.book {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
    bottom: 0;
  background-color: #D7263D;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFF;

  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: #D7263D;

  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);

  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: falta el css de book, hospital, etc... ¿no?

Comment: Como dije no lo pongo porque esta mal pero lo pondré..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer uso de `position: relative` o `position: absolute` para que `bottom: 0` funcione, ya que esta propiedad solo funciona con elementos posicionados.

Tendrías que darle la propiedad `position: relative` al div que engloba todo el texto y el botón y `position: absolute` con `bottom: 0` al botón para posicionar el botón teniendo en cuenta el div que lo engloba.

De esta manera, da igual las líneas que ocupe tu texto, el botón siempre se mostrará al final de las mismas.

Ejemplo:

```css
.cuadrado{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.boton{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadrado">
  <p>Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto Texto texto texto </p>
  
  <div class="boton">
      <a href="#">Más Informacion</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifica esta clase en el css:

```
.book { 
  width: 100%; 
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Lo que publicaste no se ve como la imagen, espero que te sirva